# iTunes: Prevent store from loading on start?

Tags: itunes

I'm running Mac OS X 10.5.8 and iTunes 10.0.1.

When I start iTunes, iTunes loads the iTunes Store. How can I stop iTunes from loading the iTunes Store upon start?

Note: I still want to have access to the iTunes Store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iTunes loads the most recent view on startup. Selecting anything other than iTunes Store or Ping in the left sidebar before closing iTunes means that the store will not load on startup. The store will then first load when you select iTunes Store or Ping.